# How does this SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF( )) function work?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, countif

I was searching for a solution to count distinct values in a range, and came across [this article](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-unique-values-in-a-range-with-countif).  The example provides a list of ten names comprised of four unique entries.  It then uses the following formula to count the four unique entries: `=SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(B3:B12,B3:B12))`

I have a basic understanding of how the `SUMPRODUCT` and `COUNTIF` functions work.  But I don't understand this formula.

- What is `COUNTIF` doing such that it yields an array of {1,2,2,3,3,3}?
- How does he `SUMPRODUCT` interact with that to yield `4`?

When I duplicate the data and enter `=COUNTIF(B3:B12,B3:B12)`, it yields `3`.

- What does this value mean?
- How is it tied to the {1,2,2,3,3,3} array?

Comment: the site you refer to has also a "how this formula works", have you read that? Your question currently is just asking for repetition of the same information. Please explain what's not clear from that and where do you need further explanation. Also (sub)results in your examples doesn't seem to be aligned, please double check them, also it's very difficult to understand formula results without seeing the input, please post that too.

Comment: I read the "How the Formula Works" section but I can't follow it. I'm not asking for a regurgitation of the link, I'm asking if someone can explain how this works in a different way or break it out more clearly.  What's not clear from the article: I don't understand how =COUNTIF(B3:B12,B3:B12) creates an array.  I don't understand how the (1/COUNTIF()) works--does this divide 1 by each value in the array?  I quoted the {1,2,2,3,3,3} array from the article--is this not correct?  Is this an arbitrary example not related to the provided example?

Comment: I also recommend stepping through the formula in Excel. I have found that to be incredibly helpful in understanding array formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `{1,2,2,3,3,3}` example is in fact completely arbitrary and has nothing to do with the actual results. The `COUNTIF()` would actually return this `{3,3,3,2,2,3,3,3,2,2}`. That array is the result of `COUNTIF()` calculating for each element of it's second argument. Then, as the article says, each element of that array is used in division with 1 as the numerator. That is, your array becomes `{1/3,1/3,1/3,1/2...}` `SUMPRODUCT()` then sums all the elements of the array to get four.